# Recorded audio won't play in Android Media player?

Tags: android, media-player

I used the following code to convert text to speech. In my code i stored the user input as .wav format. While i execute this code, every thing works fine, when i play the file it won't play.

**TTS_AudioActivity.java**

```
public class TTS_AudioActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

    private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    String destFileName = "/sdcard/wakeUp.wav";
    private EditText inputText;
    private Button speakButton, listen;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        listen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = inputText.getText().toString();
                if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {

                    HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
                    myHashRender.put(
                            TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, text);
                    tts.synthesizeToFile(text, myHashRender, destFileName);

                    Toast.makeText(TTS_AudioActivity.this, "Saying: " + text,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                }
            }
        });

        listen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

                } else {

                    MediaPlayer mpPlayProgram = new MediaPlayer();
                    try {
                        mpPlayProgram
                                .setDataSource("/sdcard/wakeUp.wav");
                        mpPlayProgram.prepare();
                        mpPlayProgram.start();
                        mpPlayProgram.release();

                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                // MediaPlayer mpPlayProgram = new MediaPlayer();
                // try {
                // mpPlayProgram.setDataSource(destFileName);
                // mpPlayProgram.prepare();
                // mpPlayProgram.start();
                // mpPlayProgram.release();
                //
                // } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                // e.printStackTrace();
                // } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                // e.printStackTrace();
                // } catch (IOException e) {
                // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                // e.printStackTrace();
                // }

                // tts.addSpeech(null, "/sdcard/wakeUp.wav");
            }
        });

        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                // success, create the TTS instance
                // tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.ENGLISH);
                tts = new TextToSpeech(TTS_AudioActivity.this, this);
            } else {
                // missing data, install it
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent
                        .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            Toast.makeText(TTS_AudioActivity.this,
                    "Text-To-Speech engine is initialized", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(TTS_AudioActivity.this,
                    "Error occurred while initializing Text-To-Speech engine",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Play" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here i stored the file in sdcard. When i play file from sdcard it won't play. How can i play the file.

Comment: it comes from the release directly after the start which stopthe recorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to release is the problem.

You called `release()` just after `start()`.
You better call release() when you are done with the MediaPlayer, as said in the documentation : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

You should read carefully this documentation, because MediaPlayer is kind of a complicated thing (in my opinion).

By the way, you should access your sdcard by using [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) and going through the files hierarchy from that call.

Comment: I made changes as per your suggestion unfortunately it won't works

Comment: Have you done some debug? Put some messages for the logcat.
You should check the return value of the mediaRecorder.isPlaying() method in the logcat.

Comment: 04-04 00:16:56.733: I/System.out(27394): MEDIA PLAYER PATH IS:::::: /mnt/sdcard/wakeUp.wav
04-04 00:16:56.733: D/MediaPlayer(27394): start() in
04-04 00:16:56.733: E/MediaPlayer(27394): start called in state 2
04-04 00:16:56.743: E/MediaPlayer(27394): error (-38, 0)
04-04 00:16:56.743: D/MediaPlayer(27394): start() out
04-04 00:16:56.743: E/MediaPlayer(27394): Error (-38,0)

Comment: Ok so what is the error, try to give a pastebin or something :)

Comment: Hm by the way, try to play a .mp3 or some other file, just to check if it is not the file which is corrupted.

Comment: Ya, i also tired to save the file in .mp3 format it saved successfully, when i play that file also won't play. I played the file by manually using the default mobile's music player it plays good. But when i play through the code it won't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9686/discussion-between-jeremy-d-and-aerrow)

Answer (score 0):

Can you comment the line `mpPlayProgram.release();` and check if it works.

The release method should be called once you want to release the mediaplayer and not while playing.